# Bazel: Java Resource folder with sqlite.db

Tags: java, sqlite, build, jar, bazel

Hi Am using bazel to build my java project. I have migrated from maven to bazel. Everything builds fine and runs.

Project Structure

```
src/main/
    BUILD
    java/
         Main.java
         ...
    resources/
         sqlite.db
         ...
```

BUILD

```
java_binary(
    name = "app",
    main_class = "com.myapp.Main",
    runtime_deps = [":libs"],
)

java_library(
    name = "libs",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    resources = glob(["src/main/resources/**/*"]),
    deps = [...]
)
```

I have `String dbLoc = com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource("sqlite.db")` in my main.java and when i print out the location of dbLoc i see the location that bazel builds the file to. it bundles the file into a jar.

So when i try to use the sqlite.db file at runtime `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbLoc)` I get an exception indicating that the file does not exist.

1. How do i build such that the db file is not bundles into a jar file? I suppose this is why the file is not found. I suppose i must build the db file onto the class path directly..
2. Otherwise what am I doing wrong here! In maven this works fine...sqlite.db is places in the targes/ folder post build

Comment: How are you running the JAR?

Comment: @Jin I am not sure what you mean by that

Comment: Are you using `bazel run` or `java -jar`?

Comment: @Jin Yes. I was using bazel run configuration in intellij ide

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by  changing

`java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + dbLoc)`

to

`java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:" + dbLoc)`